# Java MULTITHREADING - when multiple threads accesses the print method - why the execution of while method is by default synched

Tags: java

Have a doubt in multithreading.
Following is my main program to access a file, am creating 10 threads to be accessed on the object.

```
public class CallTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Test t = new Test();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Thread t1 = new Thread(t);

            t1.start();

        }

    }
}
```

Following is my program to read data from file.

```
public class Test implements Runnable {
    static int i;
    public void run() {
        try {
            i++;
            System.out.println("@@@@Count" + i);
            print();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }

    public void print() {
        try {
            StringBuilder bufData = new StringBuilder();
            File fileTest = new File("D:\\Work\\i466477");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                    fileTest));
            String strRecord = new String();
            while ((strRecord = bufferedReader1.readLine()) != null) {
                bufData.append(strRecord);
                bufData.append("\r");
                bufData.append("\n");
            }
            bufferedReader1.close();
            System.out.println("########");
            System.out.println(bufData);

        } catch (Exception exe) {
            System.out.println(exe);
        }
    }
}
```

Here I could see the code in the `while` is by default synchronized, is `BufferedReader` thread safe or because each thread will have their own copy of `StringBuilder` and `BufferedReader`? I could see the contents are read and written properly.

Comment: Yes, BufferedReader is most probably safe because it is local to the thread.  But why do you think the code in the while loop is synchronized?  What are you seeing that I'm not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that code won't be synchronized by default. Several threads could each be in the `while` loop at the same time. "Synchronized" isn't the same as "working without any problems" - did you think it was synchronized just because you didn't have any issues? In Java, `synchronized` is about only allowing one thread to execute certain critical pieces of code at a time in relation to a particular *monitor*.

Note that your access to `i` in the `run` method is unsafe, by the way. You should also close the `BufferedReader` in a `finally` block, and avoid catching `Exception`. Finally, your assignment of `new String()` to `strRecord` to start with is pointless. Hopefully these are just errors due to it being test code, but it's worth being aware of them.

Comment: I could see from the output the contents in the buffdata are synchronized, yes i is not synchronizec, i have added that to **test** for multiple threads on run method.

Comment: @Sridevi: I think you're confused about what "synchronized" means. Please explain what you observed without using the word "synchronized" and we can help you understand what's happening.

Comment: okay , thanks for the response, I used synchronized word literally - meant the contents in while loop are executed independently for each threads, hence while printing i could see the contents in **buffdata** are not messed up with multiple threads.

Comment: sample output                                                              
{1:F01PIBPITRAXTIC0000000000}{2:O1991844110408PSSTFRPPXTIC00004463350000000000N}{3:{108:110408CCPFM50525}{903:00}}{4:
:20:110408CCPFM50525
:79:/3/ LE CODE POSTAL EST 10024
TRN 383191C150000030
110316PTFR431903
EUR 500.78
VOLTOLINA ORLANDO
########
{1:F01PIBPITRAXTIC0000000000}{2:O1991844110408PSSTFRPPXTIC00004463350000000000N}{3:{108:110408CCPFM50525}{903:00}}{4:
:20:110408CCPFM50525
:79:/3/ LE CODE POSTAL EST 10024
TRN 383191C150000030
110316PTFR431903
EUR 500.78
VOLTOLINA ORLANDO

Comment: @Sridevi: That's not using it literally at all. The code *isn't* synchronized - it's just that the threads aren't interacting with each other's data, so you don't *need* synchronization. As I said in the answer, synchronization isn't a synonym for thread-safe.

Comment: okay, the threads dont share each other data because the string builder and buffer reader are local object and eac thread will have their new objects created right?

Comment: Thanks a lot Jon for the knowledge

Comment: @Sridevi: Yes, there's no need for synchronization because each thread uses its own objects... there's nothing shared (other than the file, and the OS is dealing with that).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, System.out.println is synchronized. Try this again without those.

Comment: Your answer has been flagged as a low quality post.  Please make a note of it.

Comment: @Michael - Flagging is for serious problems that require prompt moderator attention; being slightly off target or even wrong is not such a case. (Even completely incorrect answers are useful when they express a common misconception, and are adequately rebutted through comments. They can preempt the same mistake being made by others.) If you feel the answer is unhelpful (which is reasonable), you can vote against it.

Answer (score 1):

Each thread has its own StringBuilder, BufferedReader and FileReader (and operating system level file descriptor) so there won't be any interference at that level.  (None of these classes is thread-safe, but the instances are thread-confined so that doesn't matter.)

When you are writing, the `PrintWriter.print(...)` and `PrintWriter.println(...)` methods are synchronized, and that explains why you don't see output from individual println calls mixed together.  (PrintWriter is thread-safe ... and needs to be.)

Note: if you changed your code to include the thread number in each println'ed string, you *might* occasionally see the output appearing in an unexpected order.  Separate calls to a thread-safe method on the same object (the PrintWriter) don't necessarily occur in "first come, first served" order.

---

The code that updates the static variable `i` is not thread-safe, and might give you unexpected (incorrect) results every now and then ... depending on what hardware / JVM you use.  You should either do the update in a `synchronized static` method, or replace `i` with an `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: okay, thanks for the explanation, my data are not shared because, each thread have their own local string builders and buffer reader and the output statement is by default thread safe, thanks for the knowledge

Answer (score 0):

bufferreader and stringbuilder are not shared between threads, so their use is thread safe.

StringBuffer is thread safe to a degree, in that all its methods are synchronized.  BufferedReader is not thread safe.

Comment: `StringBuilder` is not thread safe. You are thinking of `StringBuffer`.

Answer (score 0):

Local variables are **thread confined**. But the non atomic operations(like `i++`) on static variable `i` is not thread safe.